# How to write REGEXP for multiple groups? (MATLAB)

Tags: regex, matlab, strsplit

I am trying to parse a text document in MATLAB and split it into sections using strsplit.  Each section is demarcated by a string that looks like this:

```
483.3731    EXP     New trial (rep=0, index=1): {u'selectPlayer': 1, u'neutralStim4': u'PSYCHOLOGIST', u'neutralStim2': u'PONG', u'neutralStim': u'YEN', u'positiveStim': u'PEACEFUL', u'neutralStim3': u'DASH', u'positiveStim3': u'HAPPY', u'positiveStim2': u'HONORABLE', u'negativeStim': u'BETRAYAL', u'negativeStim4': u'GUNPOINT', u'negativeStim3': u'JEALOUS', u'negativeStim2': u'MISTRUST', u'positiveStim4': u'AWESOME'}
```

Each section contains some variation of a number followed by 'EXP' then 'New trial' and a variable string i.e. (rep=1, index=1: {u'SelectPlayer': 2, ..).

I currently have the following code to try to parse this document but I can't get it to work!

```
expr = '\n\d+\s*EXP\s*New Trial\s*\w+\n';
filecontents = fileread('LAILA_exp1_noCBB_fMRIsync_2014_Oct_28_1239.log');
filecontents = strsplit(filecontents,expr,'DelimiterType','RegularExpression');
```

I've tried multiple variations of this regular expression but I just keep getting a single cell array containing the entire file as a string.  Could anyone lend a pointer on how to write a regular expression for a string containing multiple groups such as this one?

Thanks,
Shady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+EXP\s+New\strial\s\([^)]*\):\s+{[^}]+}
```

You can use this to match this sort of string.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/33

Comment: I am utterly amazed by your black magic!  Can you explain a little what this expression does: (?:\.\d+)?  The demo is super awesome but I don't follow its explanation.

Comment: @seldamat `?:` is just a non capturing group.`(?:\.\d+)?` is for making deimal part optional.so that only `43` and also match as well as `43.3434`.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Regex101 is so awesome - you have no idea how much easier you just made my  life.